# Finding javax.crypto substitutes

Tags: java, cryptography, javax.crypto

Does bouncycastle or anything have substitutes for javax.crypto? 
I'm using a proprietary ide and don't have the ability to add whatever libraries i want.

Main classes I need are `SecretKeySpec` and `IvKeySpec`

I'm really confused though, i can auto-import the classes into my IDE, but when I actually run the compiler can't find them even though I can go-to their source.
I checked a separate answer that said the solution lies in adding jce to the classpath, but that seems to not be an option to me. Are there any workarounds to this?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special to the classpath to get access to the classes in javax.crypto. Also, there is no class called `IvKeySpec`, perhaps you meant `IvParameterSpec`.

Comment: @JamesKPolk in that case why can my compiler not find them then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information the only thing we can recommend is to using another cryptographic library that provides its own API.

For instance, the Bouncy Castle provider library provides classes such as:

```
org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
```

and

```
org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;
```

that are a direct substitute for those two classes. Of course you are then confined to using Bouncy Castle.